# Perl: Escaping the double-quotes expanded from a variable

Tags: html, perl, escaping, double-quotes

How can I get

`my $name = 'John "FOO" Rambo';`

expanded in

`<span title=\"The great and mighty $name\"`

To something like

`<span title=\"The great and mighty John \"FOO\" Rambo\"</span>`

rather than

`<span title=\"The great and mighty John "FOO" Rambo\"`

So that my html tag is not corrupted when generating a page and the name contains `"` ?

Comment: What about `$name =~ s/"/\\"/g;`?

Comment: @rbm that does work. Never dealt with perl before :) Can you please post that as an answer? This looks much like some sed expression. Can you please also elaborate on the final `g` thing? Thanks.

Comment: OK - posted below with explanations

Comment: Please note that `\"` is not a valid HTML escape for `"`. `&quot;` is.

Comment: @el.pescado thanks, that is also true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper HTML would be the following:

```
<span title="The great and mighty John &quot;FOO&quot; Rambo">...</span>
```

You can obtain it using the following:

```
use HTML::Entities qw( encode_entities );

my $html = '<span title="' . encode_entities("The great and mighty $name") . '">...</span>';
   -or-
my $html = '<span title="The great and mighty ' . encode_entities($name) . '">...</span>';
```

You should probably be using a template system. Were you to use Template-Toolkit, the template would be

```
<span title="The great and mighty [% name | html %]">...</span>
```

Comment: And this whole time I've been manually escaping HTML entities before passing them to TT. I should have known that would be built in...time to read some docs.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, It's a builtin FILTER. It doesn't escape single-quotes, so you need to use double-quotes for your attribute value delimiters.

Answer (score -2):

**The correct HTML would be produced by using `&quot;`**

```
my $name = 'John "FOO" Rambo';
$name =~ s/"/&quot;/g;
my $html = "<span title=\"The great and mighty $name\"/>";
print $html ."\n";
```

**For clarify** on  your original question:

You can use simple regular expression to substitute quotes. 
Example:

```
my $name = 'John "FOO" Rambo';
$name =~ s/"/\\"/g;
my $html = "<span title=\"The great and mighty $name\"/>";
print $html ."\n";
```

This

```
$name =~ s/"/\\"/g;
```

simply says replace all `"` with `\"` (but since `\` is special character is needs to be escaped as `\\"`.

the `g` means `globally`, i.e. all occurences within the string.

(i.e. if you run only `$name =~ s/"/\\"/;` then `$name` would be `John \"FOO" Rambo`, but with `g` it is `John \"FOO\" Rambo`)

**But this won't produce a valid HTML**